# WinError 2 - Can't even execute print('Hello World')

Tags: python, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am trying to retake Python but I can't execute anything, I ve already googled the error but I can find anything related that the logs show me. I will appreciate any help.

- Python version 3.9.5
- Win10
- Sublime Text (Tools -> Build)

)

```
# This program prints Hello, world!
print('Hello, world!')


[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\[USER]\\Desktop\\333.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\[USER] \Desktop\]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\bin\;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python39\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\[USER] \AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
[Finished]
```

Comment: `El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado` means `The system cannot find the specified file`. I would edit it but the edit queue is full.

Comment: How did you try to run the python file ? What is a command or did you double-clicked on the program?

Comment: @Frédéric Perron
Sublime Text (Tools -> Build). I can't understand why it can't  find the same file where the code is.

Comment: You don't need to build a python file before running it. Just run the command `python filename.py`